# static header inside a scrollable div

Tags: html, scroll

I have a div that is scrollable horizontal and vertical. The problem is my header expands pretty far horizontal, as it is a table header that has a lot of columns. I want to be able to scroll left and right on the table but scroll vertical and keep that heading at the top always, but be able to scroll left at any time and show the rest of the heading. I've found some javascript examples online but i don't see any on how to do this inside a div, and I've tried to incorporate them but do not work.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
   <div style = "margin:20px 0px 7px 15px">
     <strong>&nbsp&nbspAudit Log:</strong> 
     <div style="width:750px; height:580px; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#000; background: #bbb">        
       <div style="margin:20px 0px 0px 12px">  
         <div class="container">
           <div class="heading">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width:160px">Time:</th>
                  <th style="width:210px">Source:</th>
                  <th style="width:75px">Category:</th>
                  <th style="width:90px">Ssa Admin:</th>
                  <th style="width:85px">UserID:</th>
                  <th style="width:50px">Action:</th>
                </tr>
              </table> 
            </div>
            <div wicket:id="repeaterContainer">
              <table style="table-layout: fixed; width:505px"> 
                <tr wicket:id="repeatingList" class="spaceUnder">
                 <td style="width:160px" wicket:id="time"></td>
                 <td style="width:220px" wicket:id="source"></td>
                 <td style="width:70px" wicket:id="category"></td>
                 <td style="width:90px" wicket:id="ssaAdmin"></td>
                 <td style="width:80px" wicket:id="userID"></td>  
                 <td style="width:250px" wicket:id="action"></td>     
                </tr>
              </table> 
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      div.container
      {
        position:relative;
        overflow:auto;
        width:720px;
        height:380px;
        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#000;
        background: #fff;
      }

      div.heading
      {
        position: absolute; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
        background: #bbb; 
        width:1250px;
      }
      </style>
  </wicket:head> 

  <wicket:extend>
    <script>
      $('.container').scroll(function() {
        $('.header').css({
          'left': 1250 - $(this).scrollLeft()
        });
      });
     </script>
     <p>
      <div wicket:id="tabs" class="tabpanel"></div>
     </p>  
   </wicket:extend>
```

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions at all?

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correct, that you need just scrolling tbody and whole table is in the div?